# Plot qualitative vs quantitative questions

Tags: r, plot

I run a survey with my students, I want to create a chart in R to plot specific questions. I am particularly interested in seeing the relationship between these two questions:

```
Q5. How do you find the pace of the lecture?
a) Way too fast
b) A bit too fast
c) About right
d) A bit too slow
e) Way too slow

Q8:Outside of lectures how much time a week do you devote to this class?
 _________ (hrs)
```

What kind of R chart is advisable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a [`boxplot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) could be appropriate here. Example:

```
paces <- c('wayslow','slow','right','fast','wayfast');
set.seed(1);
N <- 30;
df <- data.frame(pace=factor(sample(paces,N,replace=T),paces),outside=runif(N,5,30));
boxplot(outside~pace,df,xlab='Pace of Lecture',ylab='Hours Outside of Lecture');
```

[image: plot]

Or maybe a point plot:

```
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i');
xlim <- c(0,length(levels(df$pace)));
ylim <- c(0,(max(df$outside)+5)%/%5*5);
plot(as.integer(df$pace)-0.5,df$outside,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,pch=4,col=c('darkred','darkgreen','darkblue','darkcyan','darkmagenta')[df$pace],axes=F,xlab='Pace of Lecture',ylab='Hours Outside of Lecture');
axis(1,c(0,length(levels(df$pace))),NA,tck=0);
axis(1,seq_along(levels(df$pace))-0.5,levels(df$pace),lwd=0,lwd.ticks=1);
axis(2);
```

[image: plot2]